# How to redirect output to file and STDOUT and exit on error

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, stdout

I can exit a program on error like so

```
ls /fake/folder || exit 1
```

I can redirect the output to a file and STDOUT like so

```
ls /usr/bin | tee foo.txt
```

But I can't do

```
ls /fake/folder | tee foo.txt || exit 1
```

because I get the output of `tee` and not `ls`

How do I redirect the output to both a file and STDOUT **and** exit on error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is **exactly** what the `pipefail` runtime option is meant for:

```
# Make a pipeline successful only if **all** components are successful
set -o pipefail
ls /fake/folder | tee foo.txt || exit 1
```

If you want to be explicit about precedence, by the way, consider:

```
set -o pipefail
{ ls /fake/folder | tee foo.txt; } || exit 1  # same thing, but maybe more clear
```

...or, if you want to avoid making runtime configuration changes, you can use `PIPESTATUS` to check the exit status of any individual element of the most recent pipeline:

```
ls /fake/folder | tee foo.txt
(( ${PIPESTATUS[0]} == 0 )) || exit
```

If you don't want to take any of the approaches above, but *are* willing to use ksh extensions adopted by bash, putting it in a process substitution rather than a pipeline will prevent `tee` from impacting exit status:

```
ls /fake/folder > >(tee foo.txt) || exit 1
```